# Can all salaries on Jobs be consistently per month or per year?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I see most salaries listed on Jobs are per year. Some are definitely per month (at least I hope) like this one:

[image]

But then because the salary can be either per month or per year, sometimes there is no way to tell:

[image]

Comment: "No office location" is the way to tell.

Comment: I'm guessing the second is per year but still I think it would be helpful if they would all be consistent

Comment: @ykay you'll be disappointed, then.

Comment: Sorry I meant per year and I fixed that. In any case perhaps they should just add /year or /month if employers want to write both ways

Comment: Also it should be a good idea to add the current currency

Comment: I'm not sure fixing all displays to per month or per year is 100% appropriate, but definitely agree some indicator should be given - even if it is standardized.

Comment: I believe the year salary should be available in any case. In some countries you have more than 12 months of actual pays so if you want to correctly compare salaries between different positions you also have to check whether that particular company will give you 12/13/14 months of pays, or whether the extra ones will be smaller otherwise it's impossible to obtain an accurate yearly salary.

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** We've updated our job listing form so employers can differentiate between monthly or annual salary.  When a monthly salary is entered, we convert it to the equivalent yearly value so that salaries are consistently displayed on Jobs. If you see a suspicious yearly value, please flag the listing and we'll reach out to the company to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

We're guiding employers towards entering annual salaries because that's what we try to normalize to for search purposes. There's more work to do here and we plan to look at it in the future so I've marked this as deferred for now.