# Are salaries listed on Stack Overflow Jobs per month or per year?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

I visited Stack Overflow Jobs several times, and I have had a look at the salaries. Are those salaries paid per month or per year?

Comment: Employers should be able to indicate that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330310/can-all-salaries-on-jobs-be-consistently-per-month-or-per-year

Comment: £50k - 65k a month would be a stupendous salary for software development.

Comment: Something is very, very wrong if you see a number and can't decide if you get that amount or x12 that amount.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit - but I'm worth every penny of it!  ;)

Comment: Give him a break. People earn vastly different salaries (and even in different currencies) in different countries.

Comment: @takendarkk it is not that obvious for lower numbers. Where I live you earn less in the more rural areas because living there is cheaper. The monthly salary in a metropolis like London could become pretty close to a yearly salary where living is way cheaper.

Comment: @YowE3K sure, as am I.  If only employers/clients would understand this obvious truth!

Comment: it's not in the slightest obvious, for lower numbers. great question.

Comment: @takendarkk: Giving units is a fairly basic requirement when presenting data, for anyone over the age of about 12. Stack Overflow Jobs should be indicating this, for sure.

Comment: 12x the amount more (or less) is not that much. I would guess that a software engineer in Switzerland earns easily 12x the amount the same engineer in India. Please all keep in mind that SO is (and should be) an international side, don't just focus on the US and europe.

Comment: Damn, I thought it was an hourly rate.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Right you are. For example some junior dev in South Asia would earn 50k-65k a month (In local currency of course). That would however convert into 500-700 USD a month. So it might not be apparent to everyone that the advertised 50k is annual salary in US, not monthly.

Comment: @DavidWallace it might seem a bit low, but there are performance bonuses and dental.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The numbers you see in there are yearly. It's true that employers can enter the monthly amount, but we convert that and only show yearly salary numbers.

Comment: Why though? Is this the usual way of displaying salaries in the US?

Comment: @1615903 yes, typically salaries in the US are advertised as an annual amount.

Comment: In software industry in India , also job are offered in annual package. Here, govt jobs or some other sector have monthly salaries mentioned. However IT industry in annual package , may be because its same in US

Comment: If you enter the monthly amount does it multiply by 12? Because there are countries with more than 12 monthly salaries

Comment: Perhaps adjust the display per culture? In my culture salaries are always displayed per month, because yearly can be misleading due to many factors (vacation money, 13th month bonus, etc...)

Comment: This gives our system consistency... that should reflect the total amount you'd get for working a year for that company. So if a job pays 13 monthly salaries of $10,000 the total yearly amount is $130,000. If we made that monthly, employers should specify in the details how many monthly salaries they pay. And there wouldn't be an easy way to compare different jobs.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It’s the opposite though: If you factor in those factors like vacation money and 13th month bonus that are added *on top* of the normal monthly salary, then listing anything *but* the summed up total yearly salary is highly misleading.

Comment: @poke the point is that the yearly salary will include every dime you earn in a year. You just cannot divide that by 12 because of mentioned extra's. The amount you'll get most months is lower than year / 12.

Comment: @poke, In the US, everything beyond the actual, monetary, salary is considered "benefits". Benefits can vary dramatically between jobs, but are always, even if non-existent, part of the compensation the potential employee should consider when choosing to accept a job, or, if specified, for a job listing. Generally, if the benefits are significantly above "normal" (defined by the company's expectations of what's attractive to potential employees), then it will be explicitly stated in job listings, or during the hiring process. But "benefits" are not, normally, part of listed monetary salaries.

Comment: When I am looking at the job postings, I have to first convert to my local currency and then *divide by 12* because I am not able to judge the amount otherwise.

Comment: At the very least, "per year" needs adding to these amounts. Stating units is a really basic, fundamental requirement, that was hammered in to me from very early on in school. I'm disappointed that the pinnacle of programming communities is not abiding by it.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition "per year" is not a unit. Dollars or pounds or rubles would be a unit, and they already show those.

Comment: @TylerH "currency per year" as whole is a unit.

Comment: @TylerH: "Per year" certainly _is_ a unit (`years^-1`) (as is "US Dollars per year" which is what you'd actually be showing). A similar example, "per second" (`seconds^-1`, also known as "Hertz" `Hz`), is an extremely commonly-used unit. Look up "frequency" and you'll see plenty of instances. The only difference is that "years" is not a _SI Base Unit_ in the way that "seconds" is, although by choosing an approximation for the average length of a year, we can remedy that with a simple arithmetic multiplier; still, not all units are _SI Base Units_ (in fact, most aren't).

Comment: It would be really nice to add a switch in profile settings or something and show "per year" or "per month" label accordingly to it. It's not that I can't understand that it's an annual income (obviously, nobody pais $50k per month), I simply can't understand _how much is that_ until I divide by 12. It's very much alike converting miles to kilometers – localization. 
Multiplication by currency exchange rate would also be cool, e.g. show "5000 USD (~300k RUR) per month" on job details page (it's too much text for widget, I guess). Fetching rates once per day would be more than enough for this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, unless you're contracting, the salaries in UK are advertised with annual amount (gross).

Comment: Since salaries are referred to differently in each country, I think it would be wise to add "Yearly/Monthly" comment near each salary, because obviously it is not clear.

Comment: Oh. Then I'm not going to look for jobs on stackoverflow. Pay rate is way too low there.

Comment: It'd also be good if there was a currency exchange setting, I just saw $45-$80K, do not know what that means, if it's monthly it is a very well payed job, somewhere in the regular/good engineer wage in my country (México), but if it's yearly, it's like working on a Call Center SMH.