# Stack Overflow Jobs salary, how to know the period?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm looking in Stack Overflow Jobs and I see the salary

[image: $36k-60k]

How can I know in how much time I will receive this salary?

I know now that is annual because I did some research, but shouldn't I have something saying that it is annual? Looking at just `$36k - 60k` text doesn't give me any clue of how it works. And also, it isn't all countries that look the salary as annual, and there is a lot that is non-American on Stack Overflow.

## Edit:

Just to make clear

What I'm saying is

> Please make something explicitly that tells you the salary is annualy

I'm **NOT** SAYING

> Please change the salary rate to the same as my country

## What problem this solve

The first time you go in Stack Overflow Jobs, it's very confusing and it isn't that easy to find out that all salarys are displayed yearly.

## Edit:

Two questions was mentioned saying it was a dupe. One is my own question that I deleted and another is a question asking *[Are salaries listed on Stack Overflow Jobs per month or per year?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347846/are-salaries-listed-on-stack-overflow-jobs-per-month-or-per-year)*. My question is totally different from that, and I already did an edit explaining that.

My question is saying that you can't find in the website the information that jobs are paid annually (besides questions), and I'm asking for a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to explicitly show that Stack Overflow Jobs are paid annually.

And if you try to understand why [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347846/are-salaries-listed-on-stack-overflow-jobs-per-month-or-per-year) exists, is because the information about how the salary is paid isn't in the website.

Comment: Honestly, I've never heard of any other way that a salary is paid out.  I've seen hourly, weekly, and monthly rates as well as commission based pay, but never seen a salary described as anything other than annually paid.  [It's in the definition of the word](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/salary)

Comment: @Steve-o169 Just because you never seen it, doesn't mean it doesn't exists. You can't say it's the definition of the word from a dictionary that is in english, it's the definition of the word in english, not to all countries and languages. And if you never seen it, this is the first time you see, In brazil, the salary is monthly, nobody even thinks about it yearly.

Comment: I'm not saying "Please change the salary rate to the same as my country", but I'm saying "Please make something explicitly that tells you the salary is annualy"

Comment: But even a Brazilian should be able to understand the context of `36k-60k`.  Do you expect that a company would offer that total on a monthly basis?  If so, I need that job.  Jobs that pay nearly half a million annually don't get advertised on any old site.  They require a bit more intensive searching.

Comment: You say `be able to understand the context` ok, lets say I will pay you BR$1000, it's monthly or yearly? Most people can even know. To understand the context, you need to know the currency. What do you think is easier, understand the currency or just read a text that says `Annual Paid` ?

Comment: @Steve-o169 in my country contracts, you can see any of them: X by hour, X by month or X by year. If Jobs is supposed to serve developers around the world, they shouldn't presume that everyone uses the same system.

Comment: Regardless of currency, BR$1000 a year is ridiculously low and I would assume that's weekly or monthly.  Even the low end of the range discussed in the question, if 36k was monthly, that's 440k~ a year.  Currency only matters if the exchange rate is something crazy like US$1 compared to $10,000 in Zimbabwe.  This isn't necessary because the context of 30k+ per month is simply not feasible in most countries.  Additionally, the job search indicates a location where the position exists, thus removing any need for conversion of currency.  If the job is in the US, it's using US dollars.

Comment: @Steve-o169 you are only thinking in US way of giving salary, if you think that the context is easy to understand, maybe you are a person gifted or understand more about the world than most of people, but your case isn't the case for everybody in SO

Comment: Has nothing to do with where I live.  The top result for a job in Brazil shows a salary of `R$120k - 240k`.  Does that look like it's weekly, monthly, or yearly?  It's just common sense and reading into the context.

Comment: Still, there's bound to be an edge case where it's ambiguous. No point in leaving people guessing when it could easily be expressed

Comment: It *is* part of the definition of the word, but I agree it costs little effort to add "annual salary" to whatever employers list for the value.

Comment: That "salary" definition is cherry-picked, and even in that definition, it just says "esp. the amount paid every year", where "esp." is short for "especially". In other words, even that definition only says that there's a connotation of salaries being annual. No dictionary I could find actually defined salaries as being annual.

Comment: $36-60k could also just be a temp position. That seems reasonable for some quarterly contracts.

Comment: @Vencovsky "In brazil, the salary is monthly, nobody even thinks about it yearly". It also is the case in most of european countries as well.

Comment: It's a special case of "numbers without proper units attached are seldomly useful".

Comment: I suspect this may need a bit more info than just adding a "year". In Spain salaries are always stated per month, but also are almost always 14 pays, as in summer and winter you get paid 2 salaries traditionally. Adding 2000€/month may mislead the applicant to thing they will be paid less. What I mean is that maybe the change is not as easy as it seems. Perhaps the best option is enforcing a single standard for companies to advertise their salary

Comment: in Poland (and a huge part of europe) salary is expressed as montly exclusively, but it doesn't take long to figure out its yearly in the english speakign parts of the world

Comment: Using the term **salary** is also limiting. Corp-to-corp billing by software contractors to clients != salary,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are salaries listed on Stack Overflow Jobs per month or per year?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347846/are-salaries-listed-on-stack-overflow-jobs-per-month-or-per-year)

Comment: @amalloy second link is a deleted post. It's related to those post but I don't think it's a duplicate. The first link asks for clarification whether the salaries are displayed as monthly or annual, but this one is requesting a label stating that. Just to make it more obvious.

Comment: @amalloy just edited the question, hope now you understand that one questions is asking if the jobs are paid annully or monthly and that my question is asking for a feature resquest to show that the salary are paid annully.

Comment: @amalloy Not a dupe - that one is just a discussion, where this is a feature request.

Comment: Give it up Steve-o169, you're just wasting everyone's time and making yourself look like a wanker. If I saw R$120k - 240k I would have no idea what that meant in American dollars. For all I know that could be the same exchange rate as yen. What the poster has asked for is a reasonable and beneficial UI change.

Answer (score 8):

> How can I know in how much time will I receive this salary?

The platform should display (or make otherwise available, e.g. when hovering above the number) the full unit attached to any number. That always works and resolves any ambiguity.

Examples:

- Speedometer in a car: 60 mph
- Indicating the computing power: X TFLOPS
- Jobs listing on Stack Overflow: $60k per year

Answer (score -18):

It is fairly commonplace to display salary in yearly increments or hourly increments. While there isn't a set amount, typically you can tell by the job.

For example: `$50 rate` would be hourly (maybe up to $200 if you're doing a professional job).

whereas `$10,000 - 20,000` would be yearly. Hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: Commonplace in USA, that is. Not in Europe (except the UK).

Comment: Not in Europe - in West Europe it is

Comment: In the Netherlands is it also common to have it per month.

Comment: If you're a quant or similar worker in the US (or a manager/someone with several decades of experience), $10k to $20k could easily be a monthly salary.

Comment: In Southeast Asia, in my experience, monthly is far more common.

Comment: In South America monthly salaries are used 99.827% of the time (in the other 0.173% the interlocutor is drunk). Here in Australia it's a mix of yearly, hourly and weekly (monthly is quite rare).

Comment: Wow okay guys, just because your countries don't know how to agree on time-units doesn't mean you need to take it out on me :) 

I'll tell you how commonplace it is: EVERY SINGLE JOB I'VE EVER DONE, BOTH DOMESTIC AND INTERNATIONAL HAS USED ANNUAL OR HOURLY AS THEIR TIME UNITS. I've done a LOT of contract work and worked for quite a few startups around the globe. To say that my statement "it is fairly commonplace" is worthy of a downvote... is inane.