# Salary of contract jobs should be displayed per day

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently when [filtering jobs by contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&c=GBP&j=contract), the salary is displayed per annum, I believe it should be displayed per day for contract posts. Also you should be able to filter via Compensation per day. At least this is a common practice in the EU.

Similar: [Can all salaries on Jobs be consistently per month or per year?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330310/55075), but I'm talking about daily rates, not monthly.

Comment: Related: [Allow other granularities in denominator when specifying the minimum compensation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338093)